# Image created not being displayed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

In Visual Studio 2010, i have created a new default project and imported a JPG file called "pineapple" to the resources.

Next, i want to be able to create a pictureBox and change its image directly from the Form1_Load method, rather than drawing it from the toolbox (so i could, in another project, create an array of pictureBoxes). Here is what i came up with:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
    picture.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.pineapple;
}
```

The code compiles, however, the image doesn't show up. Why is that?

Comment: you did not add the PicBox to the form's controls collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the picturebox you have created at runtime to your form:

```
 PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
    picture.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.pineapple;
Controls.Add(picture);
```